# part of a URL show up in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a solution to have a part of a URL show up in an HTML document. If this URL changes so will the body.

for example,

[www.test.com/?key=i](http://www.test.com/?key=i) want to this show up in the body

Comment: and what've you tried so far ? StackOverflow is not a service code site

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want, has nothing to do with HTML and it is related to back-end stuff. I mean if a link changed, the body does so.

but for showing a link in an HTML page (template) you must do it like that.

```html
<a href="http://www.test.com/?key=i">http://www.test.com/?key=i</a>
```